# Is it possible for an android tv app to listen to play-stop-pause statuses?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-tv

**Background**: In a desire of automate things in my home, I'm using home-assistant. Even among the countless components, there's no such thing for "sensing" Android TV statuses (idle, playing, paused, which media is playing). Even without experience on creating android apps, I'm researching a way to integrate Android TV and home-assistant.

**Actual question**: can my android tv app, running in the background, listen to a broadcast, so that it can be notified of any playing media? Can my app know if the playing status (idle, playing, paused, which media is playing) changes?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_advanced), when the receiver loads a media queue item, it assigns a unique ID to the item which persists for the duration of the session (and the life of the queue). Your app can learn the status of the queue in terms of which item is currently loaded (it might not be playing), loading, or preloaded.

You app can also get an ordered list of all the items in the queue. The [MediaStatus](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/MediaStatus#constant-summary) class provides this status information:

- [`getPreloadedItemId()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/MediaStatus#getPreloadedItemId()) method - If the next item has been preloaded, returns the preloaded item ID.
- [`getLoadingItemId()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/MediaStatus#getLoadingItemId()) method - Returns the item ID of the item that is currently loading (but isn't active in the queue) on the receiver.
- [`getCurrentItemId()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/MediaStatus#getCurrentItemId()) method - Returns the item ID of the item that that was active in the queue (it might not be playing) at the time the media status change happened.
- [`getQueueItems()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/MediaStatus#getQueueItems()) method - Returns the list of MediaQueueItem instances as an unmodifiable list.

Use these methods together with the other media status methods to inform your app about the status of the queue and the items in the queue. In addition to media status updates from the receiver, your app can listen for changes to the queue by implementing [RemoteMediaClient.Listener](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/RemoteMediaClient.Listener).

Comment: Does this apply to any media played through AndroidTV or just for the "cast" feature?